# Cant encode list of images for face-recognition program

Tags: python, arrays, face-recognition

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
import face_recognition  
import os

path = os.getcwd() +"\\" + "known_images"

images = []  
classNames = []  
myList = os.listdir(path)  
print(myList)  
for cl in myList:  
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')  
    images.append(curImg)  
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])  
print(classNames)  


def findEncodings(images):  
    encodeList = []  
    for img in images:  
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]  
        encodeList.append(encode)  
    return encodeList  

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
```

**After writing this code to encode the images of a directory(3 images in total) one by one, using face_recognition library , it prints out this error code
`File"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\First_semester\Face_recognition\hello.py", line 26, in findEncodings encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0] IndexError: list index out of range`**

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are loading the images with cv2, but given this snippet (taken from [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#identify-faces-in-pictures) repo):

```py
import face_recognition
known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")

biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

I would say that you need to load the images with `face_recognition.load_image_file`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of the images at dataset is not ok to be encoded. So, try this code bellow. It remove the image with problems and continue encoding the rest (use folder "dataset" with subfolders with the name of the people that you collect face image):

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
import face_recognition  
import os

images = []
classNames = [] 
listNames = []
listFiles = []
myLists = list(paths.list_images('dataset'))

for (i, myList) in enumerate(myLists):
    name = myList.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{} - folder {}".format(str(i + 1).zfill(3), len(myLists), name))
    curImg = cv2.imread(myList)
    images.append(curImg)
    listNames.append(name)
    listFiles.append(myList)

def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for (i, img) in enumerate(images):
        print("[INFO] analising image {}/{}".format(i + 1, len(images)))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        try:
            encode2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
            encodeList.append(encode2)
            classNames.append(listNames[i])
        except Exception as e:
            print('removing ' + listFiles[i])
            os.remove(listFiles[i]) # remove image if not ok
    with open('encodeList.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
        for listitem in encodeList:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
    return encodeList

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
```